# How can I count how many cells are the same in both rows?

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, count

I'm currently struggling with something that seems to me like it should be quite simple.
I have the following two rows in a spreadsheet, say A and B from 1 to 5:

Strategic,  Input,  Restorative,    Learner,    Individualization

Connectedness,  Strategic,  Intellection,   Learner,    Achiever

How can I count how many words are the same in both rows? The answer in the above case should be 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This array formula should work:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MATCH(A:A;B:B;0)/MATCH(A:A;B:B;0);0))-1
```

When introducing the formula don't press enter. You have to press Control+Shift+Enter.

It should be shown like this, with curly brackets:
[image]

Comment: CSE formulas are being replaced with dynamic array formulas. You should be able to get the same result without needing to press Control+Shift+Enter. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-vs-legacy-cse-array-formulas-ca421f1b-fbb2-4c99-9924-df571bd4f1b4

Comment: Oh, thanks @BryanRock! I didn't know that, will check the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in column C from row 1 to 5 and sum the result of the values.

```
=ZÄHLENWENNS($B$1:$B$5;A1)    //German
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5,A1)        //English
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5)>0))`. Sumproduct does not require `ctrl+shift+enter` also not in older Excel versions.

PS This solution is not case sensitive.